# Append <li> innertext to php url scraper results

Tags: php, dom, text, html-lists

I have a list of links on one page:

```
<li><span><a href="https://site1.com">site1.com</a> : Description 1</span></li>
<li><span><a href="https://site2.com">site2.com</a> : Description 2</span></li>
<li><span><a href="https://site3.com">site3.com</a> : Description 3</span></li>
<li><span><a href="https://site4.com">site4.com</a> : Description 4</span></li>
```

I'm using php to take the links from one page and display them on another as such:

```
<?php
$urlContent = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($urlContent);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++){
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false){
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a><br />';
    }
}
?>
```

However, what I'm trying to figure out is how to include the description next to the link.
here is one of my many attempts:

```
<?php
$urlContent = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($urlContent);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a/li");
$li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++){
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false){
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a> : '.$li.' <br />';
    }
}
?>
```

The first part works great but everything I have tried to add the description has failed.

Comment: i believe you mean nodeValue -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue

Comment: `$xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a/li")` makes little sense, you do not have `li` that are nested inside of `a` here.

Comment: `$hrefs->item($i)->nodeValue` will get the inner text of <a> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example according to current markup:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($urlContent);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$lis = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body/li");

foreach ($lis as $li) {
    $a = $xpath->evaluate("span/a", $li)->item(0);
    $url = $a->getAttribute('href');
    var_dump($url, $a->nextSibling->nodeValue);
}
```

Here `nextSibling` is text content, which follows `<a>` tag, so `nextSibling->nodeValue` will be `" : Description"`, and you'll have to remove spaces and `:`, for example with `trim`.

Working [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/CYAoj).